# Vscode: vim plugin - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

In vsCode using vim plugin. I wanted to search regex in file (`/`), but it caused err :

```
TaskQueue: Error running task. Failed to handle key=/. Maximum call stack size exceeded. Source: Vim (Extension)
```

Does anyone know why is that and how to fix that?